# JAVA Arranging Stacks how to keep original

Tags: java, stack, runtime-error

Okay guys htis is my updated code. This is what I have. I need stack to keep it original numbers and I need stack 2,3,and 4 to keep their original numbers and right now all I'm getting is 1s 2s and 0s

import java.util.Random;

```
public class Lab5
{

  public static void main(String[] arg)
  {

Random rnd =  new Random();

Stack<Integer> stack = new IStack<Integer>();
Stack<Integer> stack2= new IStack<Integer>();
Stack<Integer> stack3= new IStack<Integer>();
Stack<Integer> stack4= new IStack<Integer>();
int stream,y;
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
  stream = rnd.nextInt(101);
  stack.push(stream);
 // stack2.push(stream);
}
   for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
      int x = stack.pop()%3;
      if(x == 0%3)
        stack2.push(x);
      if(x == 1%3)
        stack4.push(x);
      if(x == 2%3)
        stack3.push(x);
    }


while( !stack.isEmpty() )
  System.out.print(stack.pop()+" ");
System.out.println();
while( !stack2.isEmpty() )
  System.out.print(stack2.pop()+" ");
System.out.println();
 while( !stack3.isEmpty() )
  System.out.print(stack3.pop()+" ");
System.out.println();
 while( !stack4.isEmpty() )
  System.out.print(stack4.pop()+" ");
System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Comment: And which line is throwing this exception ?

Comment: you might be popping one to many in your first snippet at the `if(stack2.pop() == 0%3)` part. maybe insert a check to ensure the stack is not empty here.

Comment: I was,
updated code 
``for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
      int x = stack2.pop()%3;
      if(x== 0%3)
        stack.push(x);
      if(x == 1%3)
        stack4.push(x);
      if(x == 2%3)
        stack3.push(x);
    }
``

Comment: I can't import java.util Stack so I made the class myself

Comment: Why do you call your own class `IStack` and what is that second type `Stack`?

Comment: I have everything figured out except how to go through the first stack without popping everything off... how do I peek through the entire stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the more solutions we present, the more constraints will show up. First of all, the straight-forward solution would be to skip the pop phase and simply fill in all stacks in one go in the first place:

```
for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
    final int value = rnd.nextInt(101), x=value%3;
    stack.push(value);
    if(x == 0) stack2.push(x);
    else if(x == 1) stack4.push(x);
    else if(x == 2) stack3.push(x);
}
```

If having a pop-phase is a requirement, you can utilize the fact that a stack is actually obsolete for storing a number of values which are all the same; a simple counter would be sufficient:

```
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    stack.push(rnd.nextInt(101));

int numberOfZeros=0;
while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
    int value = stack.pop(), x = value % 3;
    if(x == 0) numberOfZeros++;
    else if(x == 1) stack4.push(x);
    else if(x == 2) stack3.push(x);
    stack2.push(value);// use stack2 as temporary storage
}
while(!stack2.isEmpty()) stack.push(stack2.pop()); // transfer back
for(;numberOfZeros>0; numberOfZeros--) stack2.push(0);
```

Finally, here is the academic solution that most likely will make your teacher happy:

create a recursive helper function:

```
static void fillOtherStacks(Stack<Integer> from,
    Stack<Integer> stack2, Stack<Integer> stack3, Stack<Integer> stack4) {

    int value = from.pop(), x = value % 3;
    if(x == 0) stack2.push(x);
    else if(x == 1) stack4.push(x);
    else if(x == 2) stack3.push(x);
    if(!from.isEmpty())
        fillOtherStacks(from, stack2, stack3, stack4);// process the rest of stack
    from.push(value); // and push back the value

}
```

and use it

```
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    stack.push(rnd.nextInt(101));

fillOtherStacks(stack, stack2, stack3, stack4);
```

All solutions use the pure stack operations `pop`, `push` and `isEmpty` which your custom `Stack` will have to implement.

Comment: I have it down so thank you anyway for the help but my new question is how do I display the stacks in JOptionPane without using strings? I'm not allowed to use containers other than what I have..

Comment: Maybe your `Stack` class should override the [`toString()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())? Otherwise, you may open a new question…

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<21;i++)
{
  stream = rnd.nextInt(101);
  stack.push(stream);
  stack2.push(stream);
}
```

After this code, your stack2 contains 21 Ints.

But when you do this:

```
for(int i=0; i<21;i++)
{
  int x = stack2.pop();
if(stack2.pop()== 0%3) ....
```

It removes 2 items per loop (since you call stack2.pop() twice) and you get a ArrayOutOfBounds Exception.
You should replace the second and for that matter all stack2.pop() codebits with x.

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this: do `stack2.pop()` only once and check. Out of bound exception was because you were doing `pop` operation more than the `stack` size.

```
 for(int i=0; i<21;i++)
  {
    int x=stack2.pop();
   if(x==0%3)
     stack.push(x);
   else
     stack.push(x);
   if(x == 1%3)
     stack4.push(x);
   else
     stack.push(x);
   if(x == 2%3)
     stack3.push(x);
   else
     stack.push(x);
```

Comment: This helps too but it doesn't keep my original ints it =turns them into 0s 1s and 2s ...

Comment: what's your requirement?

Comment: first stack is original ints (20 random integers between 0 and 100 /n
second stack is 0%3
/n
third stack is 1%3
/n
fourth stack is 2%3

Comment: Your original code @Cpt.Awesome won't do that either. You need to push your original value to a new separate stack, since pop removes from the original.

Comment: Also not allowed to use containers other than stack and can at maximum us 4 of them...which is where I'm having the trouble

Comment: That's why I tried cloning the original stack to stack2 then I was going to put values 0%3 to stack and then pop them back into stack2 after stack2 was emptied..

Answer (score 0):

`stack.pop()` will return the last item on the stack. However, it will also remove it from the stack.
Putting the result into a variable and checking against that variable instead will do what you want.

See this simplified example of what you currently are doing and why it's causing you an error

```
|
stack.push(1);
| 1 |
stack.push(4);
| 1 | 4 |
stack.pop(); // returns 4
| 1 |
stack.pop(); // returns 1
|
stack.pop(); // throws array out of bounds exception, since no more items in stack.
```